# Wild card is not working for extracting status in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Below is my table, I want to extract status starting with "QATs" but the formula is not working.

```
CRM,QATsPending
PRM,QATSInprogress
CRM,QATsOnHold
CRM,QATsCompleted,Screen
```

My formula is working

```
=IF(G2="*Pending*", "QATsPending", IF(G2="*Completed*","QATsCompleted", IF(G2="*O2InProgress*", "QATsInProgress", "QATsOnHold")))
```

It is giving on `QATsOnHold` as output.

Comment: Doesn't SUBSTITUTE do what you want? `=SUBSTITUTE(G2,"QATS","")`

Answer (score 0):

Your `ELSE` (, "QATsOnHold")))) is triggered for everything as no values in your `Table` actually EQUAL anything you are trying to match

You are also putting the value to match and the value to return in the wrong order.

It should be `Match`, `Return`, e.g. =IF(G2="QATsPending", "Pending"... not =IF(G2="Pending", "QATsPending"

Your code:

```
=IF(G2="Pending", "QATsPending", IF(G2="Completed","QATsCompleted", IF(G2="O2InProgress", "QATsInProgress", "QATsOnHold")))
```

Should be:

```
=IF(G2="QATsPending", "Pending", IF(G2="QATsCompleted","Completed", IF(G2="QATsInProgress", "O2InProgress", "QATsOnHold")))
```

But looking at your `Table`.. might actually be:

```
=IF(G2="QATsPending PRM", "Pending", IF(G2="QATsCompleted","Completed", IF(G2="QATSInprogress CRM", "O2InProgress", "QATsOnHold")))
```